# Непонятная ошибка в коде

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int User = new scan.NextLine();
}
```

Почему при таком построение кода, в строке

`int User = new scan.NextLine();`

слово scan подчеркивается красным, как ошибка?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Во-первых: слово `new` перед `scan.NextLine();` лишнее... C помощью `new` создается новый объект.

Во-вторых: `NextLine` возвращает строку, а вы ее еще пытаетесь в `int` положить...а это несоответствие типов.

Нужно либо `String User = scan.nextLine();`,

либо `int User = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());` / `int User = scan.nextInt();`

в зависимости от того, какой тип вы реально хотите 
получить.

В-третьих: `NextLine` пишется с маленькой буквы. Это все-таки *Java*, а не *C#* :-)

Comment: Только, что вписать вместо NextLine?

Comment: @МиронФисенко написал в ответе... если `int`, то `Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());`, если `String`, то `String User = scan.nextLine();` .... в зависимости от типа надо приводить к нему.. потому, что `nextLine` возвращает строку

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо убрать ключевое слово `new` во второй строке, т.к. экземпляр класса вы уже создали и инициализировали